# StreamReader vs MemoryStream.ToArray

Tags: c#

Why does `MemoryStream.ToArray` have an extra character at the start of the output string, when compared to using `StreamReader`?

```
public void StreamOutputTest()
{
    var document = new XDocument( new XElement( "root" ) );
    string actual1;
    string actual2;
    using( var stream = new MemoryStream() )
    {
        using( var writer = new StreamWriter( stream, Encoding.UTF8 ) )
        {
            document.Save( writer, SaveOptions.DisableFormatting );

            stream.Position = 0;

            using( var reader = new StreamReader( stream, Encoding.UTF8 ) )
            {
                actual1 = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            actual2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( stream.ToArray() );
        }
    }

    var expected = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><root />";
    Assert.AreEqual( expected, actual1 ); // succeeds
    Assert.AreEqual( expected, actual2.Substring( 1 ) ); // succeeds
    Assert.AreEqual( expected, actual2 ); // fails
}
```

Comment: What is the value of the extra char? Strings are null-terminated in C# ...

Comment: I think it is probably a byte order mark.

Comment: @toadflakz The extra character is at the start of the string, but its value is 65279, which I assume is just a value that was in memory at the time.

Comment: what are the values of `actual1` and `actual2`?

Comment: @webber2k6 I've added another assert to show that everything but the first character match the expected value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extra byte value of `65279` is `FEFF` in hex which is the byte order mark for UTF-16 encoding.

Read up on byte order marks here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Thank you. Why is the byte order mark UTF-16, when the stream writer is UTF-8?

Comment: Tbh I'm not entirely sure. As you said the `StreamWriter` is using the correct encoding, unless the `document.Save()` overrides that?

Comment: There are a few inconsistencies in the code posted - for example, the `StreamReader` doesn't have an explicit encoding in the constructor. That said, having experimented, the `Encoding.XXX.GetString` version of the string has the UTF16 BOM at the start if you use UTF7, UTF8 or UTF32 encodings, which seems strange! (ASCII does not...)

Comment: I think we're getting confused here by the terminology. .NET strings are by default Unicode (UTF-16) afaik. The reading method (`GetString()`) reads the format UTF-8 rather than returning a string that is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: @DanPuzey Thank you. I've fixed the StreamReader.

Comment: @toadflakz True. I checked the first 3 characters of `stream.ToArray` and they are `239 187 191`, which is the UTF-8 byte order mark, which `GetString` is converting to the UTF-16 byte order mark.